# Rails 3.2.1 - How and when RESTful routes helpers like photos_path, new_photo_path, edit_photo_path are created

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I am a beginner in learning Ruby and Rails.

I was going through the following section on Rails 3.2.1 Guide:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#paths-and-urls

which says:

```
Creating a resourceful route will also expose a number of helpers to the controllers   
in    your application. In the case of resources :photos:

photos_path returns /photos
new_photo_path returns /photos/new
edit_photo_path(:id) returns /photos/:id/edit (for instance, edit_photo_path(10) returns /photos/10/edit)
photo_path(:id) returns /photos/:id (for instance, photo_path(10) returns /photos/10)
```

I am curious to know how and when in the lifecycle of a request are these helpers, i.e. new_photo_path, edit_photo_path etc created and where in the source code I can found the code doing the same.

I was navigating through the code in the following file **/gems/actionpack-3.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb** and I guess the code in this file is creating the above helpers.Please correct me if I am wrong.

Thanks,
Jignesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially, yes, that is correct. For more information, you should check out the [Routing Walkthrough series](http://railscasts.com/episodes/231-routing-walkthrough) that Ryan Bates did last September, where he walks through some of the Rails code that controls routing.

Comment: Thanks Brandon for providing the reference.Will definitely go through the walkthrough. - Jignesh

Answer (score 0):

If you use the generators (e.g. `rails g controller NewController`) the helpers are automatically created and places in **./app/helpers** with similar nomenclature. If you are doing the controllers by hand then you would need to create your own, e.g. new_helper. By default though all controllers load application_helper.rb.

If you are not going to use a helper method in more than one controller/view it is best to put it in its own helper file. This [guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html) may help explain it more.

**Update**
The helper methods are written by you based on your needs. The code for the helper generator can be found [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails/generators/resource_helpers.rb)

Comment: I used scaffolding to generate my first sample rails application.I could find a users_helper.rb, for my User model, containing an empty module UsersHelper but it is empty.I could not find any helper methods like new_user_path, edit_user_path as I mentioned in my first post.Moreover I am interested in viewing the code which generates such helpers.However thanks for your response and the link you provided.I would surely go through that.